# Sunfounder IR remote controller issue

Tags: arduino-uno, remote-control

I've been making a hoverboard using arduino, tinkercad and c++ (pic included). When I wired it up irl, I wired it exactly as I did in the picture (arduino UNO)

However, when I tested it out, it didn't work. The IR sensor got signal from my Sunfounder IR remote, but the fans didn't turn like I expected it to. The entire thing works fine with tinkercad.

I'm really sure it's not my wiring, since I took extra extra care to wire it properly.
This leads me to believe that it's a problem with my [remote code](https://pastebin.com/XSLVX5S9)

The IR remote control used was a random one in tinkercad. I'm using sunfounder ir remote irl.
Starting line 37, I've put code that uses the remote in the tinkercad to control the motors.

Is it possible that I need to recode specifically with the cases of the sunfounder IR remote? If so, where can I find a list of what buttons are what cases/code. so that I can rewire the entire thing?

I hope you all can help me. Thank you! :)

[image: my tinkercad project]

Comment: Did you check what codes the real remote sends fpr each button? They are most likely not the same as in tinkercad. Have you tried printing the received values to Serial so that you can see them in the Serial Monitor?

Comment: why would you need a list of codes?

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that your remote is SunFounder's so I assume this is the one?

[image]

If it is then this should be the equivalent codes:

[image]

Try if it works for you.